# Beckenbach inequality for larger powers $p$?

Tags: inequality

The Beckenbach inequality states, for $x_i,y_i > 0$ and $1\leq p\leq 2$
$$
\frac{\sum_i \left(x_i +y_i\right)^p}{\sum_i \left(x_i+y_i\right)^{p-1}} \leq \frac{\sum_i x_i^p}{\sum_i x_i^{p-1}} + \frac{\sum_i y_i^p}{\sum_i y_i^{p-1}}
$$
(and the sign flips for $0 \leq p \leq 1$). My question is whether there exists, or can be proven from here, a similar result for $p>2$.

In particular, I am interested in integer values of $p\gg2$.

Comment: Have you tried computing any examples with, say, $p=3$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, indeed I've tried for some randomly generated vectors $x,y$ with $p=3,4$. I have a good feeling it cannot hold in general but not sure why...